# Add button for a modal box in my navigation

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have the following navigation in my site.

[image]

The first 3 items are normal links to other pages in my site. The last orange link opens a modal box.

This is how I have written it in code

```php
    <?php wp_nav_menu(['menu' => 'Main menu', "container" => "", "menu_class" => "desktop-menu"]); ?>
    <a class="open-modal-registration passion-one bg-orange white" href="#">Einfach anmelden und kostenlos studieren</a>
```

I have a menu that can be customized from the Control panel, and then the orange button is hardcoded.

[image]

Now comes my problem. I would like to be able to reorder the items in the navigation in a way that I can also reorder the orange button, and put it, lets say, between "Page #1" and "Page #2".

To do this, I guess I would have to add it to my menu from the Control Panel, but I do not see any proper way to do this. All that can be added to the menu are

- Custom links
- Pages
- Posts
- Categories
- Tags

And none of those elements seem the right one to define a button with such a functionality.

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are looking for and the way a WordPress menu is loaded, I would say your best bet is to add it to the menu like the other items. You can enter in all of the same data, the dead-link, style it and then use the menu item id assigned to every wordpress menu item dynamically as the selector that opens your modal. There is no need for the class you are currently using to open it since only one element will be opening the modal based on your question.

For example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

 jQuery('#menu-item-7155').click(function() {

      //add the selector/js to open your modal
      jQuery('#modal').show(); 

   });

 });
```

Hope that helps! Good luck.

Comment: This way is kinda flaky. If I create a dead-post for it, but then someone deletes it, it cannot be recovered, without touching code.